# how to resolve response of ember promise array obtained from STORE's find() method in Ember js?

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data, promise

I have a model hook for `/products` as follows :

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(controller) {
        return this.find.store('product');
    }
});
```

This works well and fetches a list of products in a JSON convention supported by RESTAdapter and I can show the list in `products` template using {{#each}} helper.

But when I get some http error (say 500 Internal Server Error), application breaks giving an error in JSON.parse. I am unable to figure out how can I make use of onSuccess and onFail callbacks here to resolve the promises properly (and handle error effectively). Any help on this topic is much appreciated.

I tried following but it's not working. Even if server is down, the flow never reaches `onFail` method.

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(controller) {
        var onSuccess = function(products) {
            return products;
        };
        var onFail = function(reason) {
            alert('Error occured !');
            return [];
        };

        return this.find.store('product').then(onSuccess, onFail);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a simple .then where the first callback is onSuccess essentially and the second is onFail

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(controller) {
        return this.store.find('product').then(function(response) {
            alert('working!'); //(you can return the models here if all is good)
        }, function() {
            alert('broken!');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @ToranBillups. Could you please look at updated question and see if I am missing something important? Thanks.

Comment: I copied this from a working app that I verified does throw on error. I'm using the latest ember-data master along with ember.js 1.4 (stable). What is your setup exactly? do you see the xhr fail in chrome dev tools to prove it "should" fail (dropping into the 2nd function) ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did exactly what you said and now I am been able to get into first callback. But when it fails, it never goes to second one, but gives me an error. May be I need to parse my response in success callback itself. Let me check it once again and get back to you. Let me know if you can help me out on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should tell the transition to abort because the model hook probably needs a real object to be returned.

To do that, use the second parameter of the model hook (it's the transition object).